# Check if byte array are all in 0xff

Tags: java, arrays, byte

Is there a simple way to check without looping whether a byte array in java has all 0xFF as values?

example

```
byte[] b = new byte[]{ 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff };

if (b is all 'ff')
    process?
```

Comment: Well in C you coul... oh.. yes, this is Java :) Sadly, I don't think that is possible (+1 for the wishlist-like item).

Comment: @JacoVanNiekerk: how would you do it in C without looping? The only way I could think of would require `b` to be fixed-sized and "small".

Comment: You cannot set byte variable to 0xff. In java byte is signed. And maximum value would be 127 (e.q. 0x7f)

Comment: @Joachim... in fact you're right.  The only speed improvement I can think of right now is viewing the array as a 64-bit array, looping to size/8, bitwise-anding each element with 0xffffffffffffffff and checking the value is 0xffffffffffffffff as well (with a special case at the end).  Looping will, as you pointed out, still occur.  I was just eluding to the fact that the Java compiler can probably not pull tricks like that out of its digital hat.

Comment: @DRCB, you can set a byte to 0xff (you have to do a type-cast though).  That is -1 in 2s-complement if displayed.  For example: byte a = (byte)0xff; System.out.println(a); will display -1 without error.

Comment: @DRCB: with type casting we can..

Comment: Does the array have a fixed length known in advance, or can the length vary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't like looping, use recursion :)

```
 public static void test1() {
    class Chk {
        boolean c(int [] b, int val, int pos) {
            if (pos >= b.length) {
                return true;
            }
            if (b[pos] != val) {
                return false;
            }
            return c(b, val, pos + 1);
        }
    }
    Chk test = new Chk();

    System.out.println(test.c(new int [] {0xff, 0xff}, 0xff, 0));

    System.out.println(test.c(new int [] {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xfe}, 0xff, 0));

    System.out.println(test.c(new int [] {0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01}, 0xff, 0));

    System.out.println(test.c(new int [] {0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01}, 0x01, 0));
}
```

Comment: But recursion is just looping in disguise! (Just as looping is just recursion in disguise!)

Comment: It depends on how you define looping :)

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do that in any language without loops (either explicit or recursive). Even if your CPU has a special instruction to check a memory area for a pattern, it will loop internally. So your question doesn't really make sense.

If you're asking for an efficient way to do this, there are ways:

- If your arrays always have the same length, you can setup a constant and use `Arrays.equals()`. If you have several different lengths but only a small number of different ones, you can create several constants.
- You can sort the array and check the first and last value. If they are the same, then all values between must be -1, too.
- You can move the check into a method, which means the "check loop" doesn't clutter the code in an important place.
- You can use JNI to access assembler code which in turn uses special instructions.
- Other languages offer better support for things like this. In Groovy, you can do `b.size() == b.count { it == -1 }`

Answer (score 1):

crazy idea, you can do it with string matching

```
int[] b = new int[]{0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};
String arr = Arrays.toString(b).replaceAll(", ", "");
String match = "\\[("+new Integer(0xff).toString()+")+\\]";
System.out.println(arr);
System.out.println(match);
System.out.print(arr.matches(match));
```